# Do we have experts here?

Tags: discussion, support

Before asking for help with our pets, especially before asking for medical advice, we should at least know if we have any professionals here. Having professionals will help us to get good answer and trust in the eye of new users. So, do we have any?

Answer (score 15):

I don't think any online site can replace professional advice that is needed for any individual situation.

There are many issues with Medical Practitioners (here in Australia at least) offering medical advice online or over the telephone. This makes it difficult when attracting professionals to some online sites, as they need to have their legal butts covered (and understandably).

It would be up to the discretion of the professional to declare their individual status and how they would proceed to use this.

I have lived with pets for nearly 50 years, I have owned dogs, cats, birds, fish and horses. At one stage we lived on acreage and housed unwanted cats, kittens and puppies to assist the local animal welfare league. I can offer my experience as an animal lover and pet owner.

As well as the fact I studied the first year of Veterinary Science, over twenty years ago (fortunately I have a good memory and remember most of it). I left the course after the first year, because we were always inflicting pain on animals, and I found some of the farming practices barbaric. I didn't like euthanizing unwanted dogs and then having them on my dissection table. Interesting animal rights movements are now slamming the very practices I found objectionable all those years ago. I actually changed to medical science.

To get back on topic, we studied animal husbandry in the first year (amongst other subjects) and this is useful for such a site. It does not make me an expert.

I should also add, I was active in our local dog club and taught puppy classes.

I have also worked on farms, lamb marking, on a pig farm and on a farm quarantining deer imported from New Zealand (which, in part, involved taking hundreds of faecal samples!).

I started riding horses at the age of four years in fact I spent most of my early childhood pretending I was a horse! There has scarcely been a time in my life I have lived without a pet. Dogs are the universe's gift to humans, if only we could be as predictable and reliable as our pets.

*edit*

I should add, I have worked for Veterinarians, assisted in surgical and aftercare.

Bred puppies (one litter). 
Followed the local obedience dog competition circuits and local dog shows (not for breed).
Handled many types of animals.
Have some experience with Australian wildlife and handling them when they come into domestic environments.
It has been a continual life long passion of (em) 46 years.
Having studied medical science and worked in a hospital, the medical experience, although human, assists in understanding health problems with pets. (But this does not make me an expert, just reasonably capable of discerning when there is a potential health problem)

I will  add things if I have forgotten them.

Comment: We are very glad to get you as a member. I am more than sure you are a perfect suit for this site and your domain knowledge as well as in medical field will help us a lot.

Answer (score 6):

We are currently within the first 24 hours of private beta.  We should be asking questions for the audience we hope to build, not the people who are here now.

That said, this isn't the place to get specific, individualized professional advice, but I hope we will attract veterinary professionals who engage on the less-specific questions of their field.  For example, I wish this site had existed several years ago when my vet was trying to figure out a course of investigation for my cat's unusual problems; she could have asked (well, had me ask; she's not on the Internet) here instead of trying to find information in assorted journals.

Comment: Agreed with you that we are only 24 hour old but if you notice we have show great response within 24 hours, so why to wait to ask such question.

Comment: I'm just saying that the presence or absence of professionals *now* shouldn't much affect how you use the site.  Ask your questions!  If it takes a few days (or weeks) to get answers, oh well.  If you get professional-grade answers, you'll know who's here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am very excited to have found this site, but unfortunately one problem we are going to deal with is people who think of themselves as experts because they have had a dog or a cat or a hamster, or because their grandmother had a dog.

There is also a large bit of subjectiveness when it comes pet care and a lot of myth vs fact, so it will be very difficult for an expert's voice to be heard amongst the noise.

It will be necessary to use our downvotes pretty heavily and commenting why, especially early to try to discourage promoting incorrect information and ensure the best quality answers rise to the top.

Comment: Down-vote is a good advice in the mention cases and till now i have seen quite a good answer and users. So i think we will surely can handle this.

Comment: Many sites covering subjective material have this problem.  The key is for everybody to be honest about what we don't know.  We don't require VMD or better to participate, but don't guess and pass it off as more, either.

Comment: Very true.  My point was beyond private beta when any Tom, Dick, or Harry can join, we might see this as a larger issue.  This is my first serious foray into a more subjective SE site, so I've not seen how other communities handle this.

Comment: It's gonna be a tough one and I expect a lot of meta questions about how to handle the somewhat inherent subjectivity. Clear community guidelines can help, but SE sites pride themselves on providing expert answers so I think, most of all, we need to attract experts. Not just vets but also professional trainers, animal behaviourists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I myself am no expert on pets.

I own a dog, but more importantly, I think we should focus on *sources*.

**You shouldn't need to be an expert to participate here.**

We need to encourage non-experts to support their answer with credible sources rather than just prior knowledge to ensure that the information is true.

That's what I try to on all of my answers here to show that my answer can be backed up, even if I am not an expert on that specific subject.

It may also be important to leave a disclaimer if the question asks for information that could decide their pet's life (such as medical questions).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not an expert. But I have a dog of German Shepherd breed and a friend of my brother possesses a dog-kennel. I visit that place a lot and spend time with him and his dogs. So I have quite a good experience with handling dogs, which in turn gives birth to expertise, I guess. :-)

Comment: I am seeking for medical adviser like professional pet doctor etc.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, Is this veterinary.SE? I don't think so!

Comment: But if we have pet veteran then it will be a + for us. We have similar question asked over other meta of SE's such as SFF and MTV.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, Yeah, I understand. But actually veterinary is not synonymous with having pets, It is a subset of pets. there are other attributes of pets too, like "behavior" (_mostly_),"physique", "mentality", "nutrition", "habits" etc. When the discussion comes to health-problems, we need a veterinary doctor. So your point is not invalid, but it is **one of** the qualities, not a single all in all one.

Comment: Completely agree with you but just want to know are we capable of answering medical problems here.